# How to cancel the file copying in c#?

Tags: javascript, c#

I have added the below codes to copying the files in my local machine. In my case, if the user click the cancel button, i would like to stop the file copy progress using c#. My code is below.

**JS code:**

```
for(var i = 0; i < file.length; i++){
   var formdata = new FormData();
   formdata.append("Files", file[i]);
   var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
   ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
   ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
   ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
   ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
   ajax.open("POST", "/Save");
   ajax.send(formdata);
}
```

**C# code:**

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    using (Content)
    {
        Content.CopyTo(stream);
    }
}
```

I have the cancel button to cancel the file progresss. In that i have aborted the ongoing progress. I have tried the abort() in xml to block the request but it doesn't block the file copying. How can i achieve my requirement.

Comment: Have you tried using the async version ? `CopyToAsync` I believe it comes with a cancelation token

Comment: You can't abort the HTTP and you can't interact with the filestream from the client, so this is impossible. @Greggz making the fileststream async will not make any difference. Once the server gets the request it will do one atomic task then respond. You have no way to tell this atomic task to stop.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look on the Async method with the Cancelation token ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158751(v=vs.110).aspx))

In save you create a CancellationTokenSource ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))
 and store it somewhere

Your cancel button then call another endpoint like Cancel (inspired ;) ) that call the Cancel() method on you tokenSource. (CancellationTokenSource has a Token property for your CopyToAsync call)

Regards,
Benoit.

ps: you may want to store some unique id along the request if you want to have several users on several files.

EDIT based on @greggz and @Liam comments:
You should also move your HTTP endpoint to an async one :)